# how to get refresh history for all datasets on workspace in powerbi

Tags: azure, rest, powerbi, azure-synapse

Please help

How can I get the refresh history for all datasets in workspace, on powerbi - I tried the below method but its only specifying for a single dataset

GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D/refreshes)

Will also want to create the pipeline that will save the results in datalake

I tried using this method but only specifying one dataset at a time

GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D/refreshes)

I am expecting to to get refresh history for all datasets, create a pipeline that will save the results in datalake

Comment: Are you using **azure-synapse**?

Comment: Yes Aswin, I'm using synapse

Answer (score 2):

A few things here, if you wanted to easily get the last 7 days of history on a go forward basis, I would use the Power BI Admin APi call at this link:

[Power BI Admin Refreshables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/get-refreshables)

If you really need to get a full history of dataset refreshes, unfortunately you will need to use the groupID and datasetId to get the history for each dataset.

The good news here is you can first get all datasets using the below API Documentation (Power BI Admin API, GetDatasetsAsAdmin):

[GetDatasetsAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/datasets-get-datasets-as-admin)

**Note: If you do not have admin capabilities in Power BI, you can use this APi call to get the Datasets within a particular workspace:

[Get Power BI datasets without Admin Privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-datasets-in-group)

Once you have the results, you can write that to your DataLake.

You can then use Synapse or ADF to iterate over your dataset list and return dataset refresh history for each dataset using this API Call:

[Get Refresh History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-refresh-history)

Here is an illustration of an ADF pipeline (very similar to synapse if I'm not mistaken):

**Get Power BI datasets**

[image: Get PowerBI datasets loaded]

**Iterate on All Loaded datasets**

[image: Load Refresh History to DataLake]

This should work nicely as I have been doing this for a couple years now, though I just use the simple Admin API call to get the last 7 days of refresh history in a single call for all datasets.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for assistance, can you please clarify a bit more on the foreach activites, I am lost

Comment: Sure, assuming you have already written the list of datasets to a DB or DataLake, you can then use a Lookup activity to pull all datasets from your DB or DataLake (from whatever table you saved the datasets to). Then you connect a For Each activity to that lookup so that for EACH dataset you can run an API call that pulls the Refresh history for that dataset. eg if you have 30 datasets, the FOR EACH will run 30 API calls to retrieve the refresh history. You can also write the output of those API calls to a DB or DataLake. Hope that helps

Comment: This has a good example of a Lookup -> For Each

https://helicaltech.com/lookup-foreach-activity-azure-data-factory/